# How to type the micro sign μ on Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard, unicode, character-map

I frequently find myself googling "micro sign" when I need to type the micro sign μ.

Is there an easier way? How can I type this sign using my keyboard?

I am on macOS Monterey using the ABC Extended keyboard (in English).

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using ABC Extended rather than any 'normal' English? [If it's because you need specific characters, let us know *which* characters & maybe we can find them on a 'regular' English too]  µ is Opt/m on most English layouts, but isn't available at all on ABC.

Comment: Pic of ABC with Opt pressed - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTeej.png Pic of British English with Opt pressed - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVp0r.png

Comment: @Tetsujin I've deleted my comment, as it seemed to work briefly when on ABC Extended, but then I deleted ABC Extended from my input sources and re-added it, and no longer works... However ABC (not extended) does support Opt/m combination

Comment: Yes, ABC is almost a simple 'international' English [British with swaps for pound, cents & Euro to be more like US English]. Extended gets happy with dead keys. They're not really similar. [I ought to have made that distinction at the end of my first comment, but too late now]

Comment: In regards to how you can easily do it, you could enable ABC (not Extended) keyboard layout in System Preferences, and then temporarily switch to it using `Control`+`Space` command to shuffle through your keyboard input sources and then press `Option`+`m` to obtain the `μ` (mu) character ... Or alternatively you can make your own text replacements in `System Preferences`>`Keyboard`>`Text`. Since I use LaTeX in my mathematics studies, I just use their convention, so I set `μ` to automatically replace `\mu` whenever I type that combination of characters

Comment: @Tetsujin no, I think that's what the OS came with when I bought my MacBook. I'll switch to normal English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> when using the **ABC** keyboard layout (which is equivalent to the US keyboard layout) should print `µ`.

---

#### Additional info

You can also use the **Unicode Hex Input** keyboard layout<sup>1</sup> and type **O3BC** (which is the [hex code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(letter)#Character_encodings) for `µ`) while holding the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key to write `µ`.

**Note:** You can also type **00B5** while holding <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> to write `µ` (see [Character encodings - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(letter)#Character_encodings)).

<sup><sup>1</sup>Basically, the Unicode Hex Input keyboard layout allows you to enter any character by typing its hex code while holding the <kbd>⌥  Option</kbd> key. It could be added in *System Settings > Keyboard > Text Inputs* (on Ventura).</sup>